# lagrange algorithm in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I wrote a javascript version of Lagrange algorithm, but it kept going wrong when I run it, I don't know what went wrong. 
I use this to calculate time.
When I pass a cSeconds as a variable, sometimes it returns a minus value which is obviously wrong...

```
function LagrangeForCat(cSeconds){


var y = [2592000,7776000,15552000,31104000,93312000,155520000,279936000,404352000,528768000,622080000,715392000,870912000,995328000,1119744000,1244160000,1368576000,1492992000,1617408000,1741824000,1866240000,1990656000,2115072000,2239488000,2363904000,2488320000,2612736000,2737152000,2861568000,2985984000,3110400000,3234816000,3359232000,3483648000,3608064000];

var x = [604800,1209600,1814400,2592000,5184000,7776000,15552000,23328000,31104000,46656000,62208000,93312000,124416000,155520000,186624000,217728000,248832000,279936000,311040000,342144000,373248000,404352000,435456000,466560000,497664000,528768000,559872000,590976000,622080000,653184000,684288000,715392000,746496000,777600000];


    var l = 0.0;
    for (var j = 0; j < 34; j++) {
        var s = 1.0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 34; i++) {
            if (i != j)
                s = s * ((cSeconds - x[i]) / (x[j] - x[i]));
        }
        l = l + s * y[j];
    }

    var result = l / (24 * 60 * 60);

    var Days = Math.floor(result);
    //get float seconds data 
    var littleData = String(result).split(".")[1];
    var floatData = parseFloat("0."+littleData);
    var second = floatData *60*60*24;

    var hours = Math.floor(second/(60*60));
    var minutes = Math.floor(second % 3600/60);
    var seconds = Math.floor(second % 3600) % 60;

    var returnData = {days:Days,hours: hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds}
    return returnData;
}
```

Comment: Sample input/output please?

Comment: @AmardeepBhowmick  (Real data) Input:63119321,and output: days is -79288, and I guess the hours, minutes doesn't matter

Comment: This could be interesting to debug, but could you supply the actual code with the definition of x and y (var y = [2592000,7776000,15552000,31104000,....];
    var x = [604800,1209600,1814400,2592000,....];
 I don't know what the other 30 values for each array are) and a link to the description of the algorithm you're implementing. Also you say you get negative values which are obviously wrong, but do you get sometimes the correct value ?

Comment: If I am not wrong, I could not find `catDays` in your code.

Comment: @EponymeWeb The whole algorithm I wrote is up there, and I updated x and y, please check it out, thank you!

Comment: @AmardeepBhowmick Sorry, made a mistake, I updated my code, please check it out, Thank you

Comment: What you actually want is probably some kind of table look-up with higher order interpolation. I would use at most degree 3 interpolation polynomials using the 4 closest points around the given value for `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the issue is with your code but with the data set.

I tried a few things, for instance if you have cSeconds = one of the x values, then you get the correct result (I could check that it was equal to the matching y value).
I put all the data in open office and drew the graph it was like the square root function but more extreme (the 'straight' part look very straight) then I remembered that when you interpolate you usually get a polynomial that crosses the points you want but can be very wild outside between the point.

To test my theory I modified the algorithm to control at which x/y index to start and tried for all the values:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 35; ++i) {
    LagrangeForCat(63119321, i, 34)
}
```

Together with a console.log inside LagrangeForCat it gives me the interpolated y value if I use all the x/y arrays (i=0), if I ignore the first x/y point (i=1), the first two (i=2), ...

```
00-34 -6850462776.278063
01-34   549996977.0003194
02-34   718950902.7592317
03-34   723883771.1443908
04-34   723161627.795225
05-34   721857113.1756063
06-34   721134873.0889213
07-34   720845478.4754647
08-34   720897871.7910147
09-34   721241470.2886044
10-34   722280314.1033486
11-34   750141284.0070543
12-34   750141262.289736
13-34   750141431.2562406
14-34   750141089.6980047
15-34   750141668.8768387
16-34   750142353.3267975
17-34   750141039.138794
18-34   750141836.251831
19-34   750138039.6240234
20-34   750141696.7529297
21-34   750141120.300293
22-34   750141960.4248047
23-34   750140874.0966797
24-34   750141337.5
25-34   750141237.4694824
26-34   750141289.2150879
27-34   750141282.5408936
28-34   750141284.2094421
29-34   750141283.987999
30-34   750141284.0002298
31-34   750141284.0000689
32-34   750141283.9999985
33-34   3608064000
34-34   0
```

Exclude 33-34 and 34-34 (there's just not enough data to interpolate).
For the example x=63119321 you'd expect y to be between 715392000 and 870912000 you can see that if you ignore the first 2-3 values the interpolation is "believable", if you ignore more values you interpolate based off the very straight part of the curve (see how consistent the interpolation is from 11-34 onward).

I use to work on a project where interpolation was needed, to avoid those pathological cases we opted for linear interpolation trading accuracy for security (and we could generate all the x/y points we wanted). In your case I'd try to use a smaller set, for instance only two values smaller than cSeconds and two greater like this:

```
function LagrangeForCat(cSeconds) {

    var x = [...];
    var y = [...];

    let begin = 0,
        end = 34
    for (let i = 0; i < 34; ++i) {
        if (cSeconds < x[i]) {
            begin = (i < 3) ? 0 : i - 2
            end = (i > (x.length - 1)) ? x.length : i + 1
            break
        }
    }

    let result = 0.0;
    for (let i = begin; i < end; ++i) {
        let term = y[i] / (24 * 60 * 60)
        for (let j = begin; j < end; ++j) {
            if (i != j)
                term *= (cSeconds - x[j]) / (x[i] - x[j]);
        }

        result += term
    }

    var Days = Math.floor(result);
    // I didn't change the rest of the function didn't even looked at it
}
```

If you find this answer useful please consider marking it as answered it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Just don't understand why there this data set  does not work

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, I noticed that it wasn't very "stable". If you consider the 3 points (-1, 0), (0, 0) and (1, 0) they're aligned yet the polynomial crossing them x(x-1)(x+1) wouldn't give you a good interpolation.